# smartctl looks like it's giving incorrect results, is my SSD dying?

Tags: ssd, smart, btrfs

While backing up some files today, I noticed that btrfs complained that some blocks on my Crucial MX500 1TB SSD didn't have the correct checksum. I ran a `btrfs scrub` which reported this:

```
● btrfs-scrub@-.service - Btrfs scrub on /
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/btrfs-scrub@.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-12-06 17:22:25 CET; 3h 56min ago
TriggeredBy: ● btrfs-scrub@-.timer
    Process: 4046 ExecStart=/usr/bin/btrfs scrub start -B / (code=exited, status=3)
   Main PID: 4046 (code=exited, status=3)

dec 06 17:22:25 redacted btrfs[4046]: Status:           finished
dec 06 17:22:25 redacted btrfs[4046]: Duration:         0:16:05
dec 06 17:22:25 redacted btrfs[4046]: Total to scrub:   308.05GiB
dec 06 17:22:25 redacted btrfs[4046]: Rate:             320.15MiB/s
dec 06 17:22:25 redacted btrfs[4046]: Error summary:    csum=10
dec 06 17:22:25 redacted btrfs[4046]:   Corrected:      0
dec 06 17:22:25 redacted btrfs[4046]:   Uncorrectable:  10
dec 06 17:22:25 redacted btrfs[4046]:   Unverified:     0
dec 06 17:22:25 redacted systemd[1]: btrfs-scrub@-.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=3/NOTIMPLEMENTED
dec 06 17:22:25 redacted systemd[1]: btrfs-scrub@-.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

So it looks like only 10 blocks were corrupted, which made me think that it wasn't actually a hardware error but just some bug. Just in case I ran a couple of SMART tests (two `short` and two `offline`). After that, the output of `smartctl` looked like this:

```
smartctl 7.0 2018-12-30 r4883 [x86_64-linux-5.4.1-2-ck] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-18, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Crucial/Micron BX/MX1/2/3/500, M5/600, 1100 SSDs
Device Model:     CT1000MX500SSD1
Serial Number:    1845E1D544F0
LU WWN Device Id: 5 00a075 1e1d544f0
Firmware Version: M3CR023
User Capacity:    1 000 204 886 016 bytes [1,00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.3, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Dec  6 21:14:57 2019 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  30) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x0031) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  5 Reallocate_NAND_Blk_Cnt 0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1266
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1820
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Ave_Block-Erase_Count   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       8
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       69
180 Unused_Reserve_NAND_Blk 0x0033   000   000   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       37
183 SATA_Interfac_Downshift 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 Error_Correction_Count  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   057   045   000    Old_age   Always       -       43 (Min/Max 0/55)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
202 Percent_Lifetime_Remain 0x0030   100   100   001    Old_age   Offline      -       0
206 Write_Error_Rate        0x000e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
210 Success_RAIN_Recov_Cnt  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
246 Total_Host_Sector_Write 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5740642566
247 Host_Program_Page_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       93790426
248 FTL_Program_Page_Count  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       97088644

SMART Error Log Version: 1
Warning: ATA error count 0 inconsistent with error log pointer 2

ATA Error Count: 0
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error -1 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 0 hours (0 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  00 ec 00 00 00 00 00

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:00:00.000  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:00:00.000  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:00:00.000  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:00:00.000  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  c8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:00:00.000  READ DMA

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1266         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1263         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

So the drive passed the tests, reports a `Raw_Read_Error_Rate` of 0 and zero ATA errors, but `smartctl` still displays a mysterious error -1 that happened at 0 hours.

Is my drive actually about to die or is it just a glitch?

Comment: You did a short test. That’s not enough. // Did you check/swap the cable yet?

Comment: What does `btrfs device stats /` show?

Answer (score 2):

Your SMART data looks to be in excellent state, no worries there.
For peace of mind you could run `fsck` on the file-system, but the disk is fine.

For the error message see the Smartmontools FAQ section
['Warning: ATA error count 9 inconsistent with error log pointer 5' What's the meaning of this smartctl message?](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/FAQ#Warning:ATAerrorcount9inconsistentwitherrorlogpointer5Whatsthemeaningofthissmartctlmessage)

> The ATA error log is stored in a circular buffer, and the ATA specifications are unambiguous about how the entries should be ordered. This warning message means that the disk's firmware does not strictly obey the ATA specification regarding the ordering of the error log entries in the circular buffer. Smartmontools will correct for this oversight, so **this warning message can be safely ignored by users**. (On the other hand, firmware engineers: please read the ATA specs more closely then fix your code!).

You could run more disk tests to be sure, but I do not think that there
is any reason to suspect a failing disk.